How would a Magic-Fueled Industrial Revolution shape social classes in cities?
In short:
The setting is an Earth-like fantasy world where growth-accelerating devices, mana-fueled factory machines, and fast-flying barges have been created. These three inventions increased food surplus, improved productivity, and accelerated transportation, sparking an Industrial Revolution equivalent.
The main differences between the real-world Industrial Revolution and this one are:

These inventions require more educated workers to function. These special workers use their mana and magical training to both fuel the machines and control them. Assume at least one of them for every car-sized machine or floating barge. There are still plenty of menial tasks to justify the need for unskilled labor.
The fabrication of magic machines takes longer than steam engines, and benefits a little less from economy of scale. As a result, their industrial use took a couple more generations to spread.
Flying barges can only hover and move above bodies of water (rivers, canals, lakes, etc.), which take the role of train tracks.
Coal and steel are less used, but mining is still required, as every single type of metal, crystal, ceramic, gems, and glass is potentially useful in building and maintaining these machines.

The question:
What would be the social and urban impacts on cities?
At first, I assumed my setting would be something like "1850 Paris or London, with less smog," but I now have doubts.
I am only interested in big cities and how they would develop during the first century of this Industrial Revolution, and what their social makeup would be.  Especially if the division and size of rich and poor neighborhoods would be different, and the probability of the working class living under the same conditions as our world.
I am not interested in the devellopment of empires, cultures, traditions, architecture, art, etc.
If possible, I'd prefer answers to include examples and/or comparisons to real-world cities in the 19th century. Preferably London or Paris, but if necessary it could be any other capital city of the time.
Extra information:
Below are some background details, they may be unecessary to write an answer
This world’s technological evolution was roughly similar to ours until the 18th century. One major difference is that large-scale use of the steam engine was stunted because the biggest coal deposits are infested with dragon-moles, making their exploitation impossible.
Humanity has always had the ability to perform magic. However, to cast even the most basic spell, one must spend years—decades, even—in training. Magic has always held tremendous cultural and religious significance, but it was never powerful nor common enough to affect agriculture, warfare, public health, industry, or commerce.
One key rule in this world is that the effects of enchanted objects can't be triggered mechanically. They cannot be activated by word, movement, lever, button, moonlight, timer, etc. The only way is for a mage to use their sixth sense to control the enchantment embedded in the artifact. It's extra difficult if they have not been trained in the exact school of magic that created the enchantment, and even if they are they still must spend a few months getting familiar with it. Similarly, potions are just gross goo to untrained people. Only alchemists can gain any benefit from consuming them.
The invention of simplified and standardized enchantments changed everything. Someone who has learned how to operate a mana-engine can attune to a similarly enchanted engine in a matter of minutes. Now, anyone can spend only three years in a Magitek Technical School and be able to make any of these machines work. A diligent worker can learn to operate them within a decade of performing menial jobs (pushing carts, feeding them powders and liquids, etc.) around them and meditating regularly. Children born of women working these machines can learn even faster.
The workers must still be mentally controlling the machines during the whole duration of their operation.
The first three major inventions are: scarecrow-like devices that accelerate plant growth, machines that enable production lines similar to ours, and barges that can fly over bodies of water (and each other).
After that, a multitude of less impactful inventions follow as the newly created "Standardised enchanting" and "Magitek operation" schools of magic gain traction across the world, but from the very start all industries require workers with specialised and prestigious (as is anything related to Magic) training to operate.
Related :
What school of magic would the upper class want their children to learn quickly?

A wrench to throw into your reasoning - if the motive power is magical, but glass and ceramic are key resources, you've wrapped back around to needing a major source of cheap fuel for fire.  Also, very early in industrialization they used wood before switching to coal, so if coal is inaccessible, your forests would be in danger of being depleted.

In the real-world history of the real-world industrial revolution, those enchantments are called patents of invention. And yes, in order to use them one needs to spend years, even decades learning the particular branch of technology where they apply; and yes, they are basically useless to those trained in some different branch of technology. (And I really don't see why using the word mana instead of coal would change anything. After all, different languages already have different words for coal. A fuel is a fuel.) (And there is nothing cheaper than steel which can do what steel does.)

@Jedediah Glass and ceramics can be used to make the machines, but they can be also made with any other types of metals, naturaly occuring crystals, etc... What I meant is that every single minable resource can potentialy be used to build them

@AlexP "in order to use them one needs to spend years training" -> I thought that IRL many factory workers where trained on premises, and in a shorter time than that. I still think that the use of people's mana as fuel instead of coal has the potential to affect how society would devellop

@BabiBaba: (1) The question does not say anything about people's mana. It just says that the machines which power the factories burn a fuel called mana. That's just another name for coal. (2) Factory workers are not using the enchantments. The engineers are. That's the entire point of a true industrial revolution: you don't need to be a trained artisan in order to make glass. If you have to be a trained artisan in order to make glass then the industrial revolution is still far in the future.

@AlexP  The factory workers need to stay next to the machines and use their magical senses to keep them turning. I'll edit the question to make it clearer. English isn't my first language, please tell me if any other part is in need of clarifications

Please read about high concept questions then [edit] your question to be well focused with the possibility of objectively selecting one best answer (i.e., explain how you'll objectively select a best answer) to avoid closure. Thanks.

This question does not have one answer. During the industrial revolution of countries we can see a multitude of social structures. It is more determined by what came before. Magic also does not mean you're out of the woods. Magic could cause pollution just like normal fuel. It could be that the magic fuel has identical byproducts. It could wear the magician. It could change the laws of physics in an area over time. The range is too broad and not well defined. As the question is now, you can basically do whatever you want. Such is the flexibility of writing.

@JBH Hi! I have edited the question to add emphasis to the fact that I am only interested in the devellopment of big cities and am looking for answer containing comparisons to real-life cities, is it clear enough now ?

@Trioxidane Hi! Magic does not add any new types of pollution or byproducts, no extra wear on the magicians, and does not alter the laws of physics in an area over time. I am not interseted in specific social norms or cultural practices, only in the economic stratification of big cities.  Are there other parts of the setting that needs further clarifications ?

@BabiBaba You might be misunderstanding the basic nature of Stack Exchange. You're obligated to ask a question that has a reasonable change of having a single best answer. Worse, Stack Exchange has what it calls a "Book Rule," meaning that if the answer can be reasonably answered with something the size of a book, it's off-topic. You're asking for a LOT, especially if you're expecting lists of examples from existing cities. I still believe you have a high concept question. It's important to understand SE is not a free research site. You're expected to perform primary research ...

... and ask here if that research fails you, meaning you have the ability to explain specifically why the research failed you. (See [ask].) Frankly, a quality answer to this question would be on par with a doctoral thesis. It's not a well-scoped question. Do we focus on water supply? sewer? jobs? housing? air quality? transportation? One of those is a big question, and yet you seem to be asking for all of them and a lot more. People go to school to become experts in urban planning and impact.

@JBH I think both frame challenge answers are pretty good. They are short ans well explained. I am not interested in any of the détails you're listing (water supply, jobs, etc.), only in how pour/medium/rich populations living areas would be structures relatively to each other. I may have not be clear enough.

@JBH Sorry, I'll on mobile (without English auto correct). I am not asking for a long liste of cities either, only points of comparaisons to help me understand thé answers.

Your Cities Shrink at the Start of your Revolution
The real change-from-historical thing here is growth-accelerating devices (GADs).
GADs make farming less manpower-intensive by Nth power, where N is "whatever you handwave."  The problem here is, with mana-powered factories your rural population doesn't have masses of new unskilled labor jobs to get in the cities.  Which means they stay rural, creating a population boom in the countryside while simultaneously making it so a family needs less land.  Suddenly farming isn't quite-so-difficult, and since land can be broken down into smaller allotments you're going to see short-term MASSIVE growth of the countryside population.
After a couple generations when smallholders are once again farming the-minimum-sized-plot-to-live-on. But in between times you'll probably have a helluva time convincing the peasantry to move into (traditionally disease-ridden to the point where they relied in immigration to maintain population) cities.  So your cities are liable to SHRINK at the start of your industrial revolution rather than grow.  Which means your "mana-powered factories" will either be commensurately smaller (with lots of little factories all over the place rather than a centralized city/couple cities doing the majority of production) OR you'll have a TON of investment into canals/artificial rivers so that the centrally-produced goods can rapidly be distributed to the rural population.
Mana-fueled factory machines should be able to do all the things steam power did for civilization as far as improving mining goes, which was a HUGE thing for the industrial revolution.  Even leaving aside things like coal-powered steam engines and the like, you're going to have a massive population increase and those folks will need coal for heating/cooking/whatnots.
Your barges aren't going to change a whole lot compared to real revolution.  Construction of canals/artificial riverways is going to take over from railroads, and that'll mostly be that.  Though depending on how out-of-the-box your governments are thinking a "floating fort" would make a GREAT rebellion/riot suppression tool for nations/regions with lots of irrigation farming. Most cities are likely to have some sort of (probably really nasty-looking) open water system for police/military quick deployment during civil unrest.

Wow this makes a lot of sense. If thé initial increase in production came from small factories based in small towns then would production eventually move to bigger cities ?

The demand for food is not going to increase until the population increases proportionally, if anything, the increased ease of production is going to cause prices on food to crash and only the most efficient farmers will remain in business.  The more likely effect is that the land furthest from the cities/towns (ie with highest transport costs) will become completely unprofitable to farm and will end up being vacant or inefficiently farmed by people with nowhere else to go.

Pre-industrial farmers were more-or-less constantly suffering from food insecurity.  That's one of the reasons fatalities for children under 3 were so high.  The population increase (in the form of children not dying from malnutrition or related causes) is going to essentially be concurrent with the increase in food production.  They'll still have to create the GADs and convince people they work etc etc., so they'll be an upswing in food production and 1000% more efficient next day.  If you have 9 kids expecting 5 to die before age 3 but they ALL live, your demand is going to grow quickly!

Babibaba that's probably up to you.  I'd think at some point it would, but when exactly that point is depends a lot on the way you choose to depict the training of magicians and just how much less building all these devices benefit from economies of scale.

By restricting Magic to classically educated and trained individuals, you made social inequality so much worse, because your average worker cannot afford to be able to seize the means of production, by force, skill, or purchase.
So your Industrial Revolution happens along the lines of Old Money/Old Magic getting richer, and society being split into Mag and No-Mag classes pretty starkly. You barely get the cultural change of the New Rich factory owners replacing old feudal Lords, the Magic Lords are the Factory Barons. Feudalism seamlessly grows into stratified capitalism.
Second issue: Classic Industrial revolution depended on key resources like coal, iron, copper, tin, etc being easily available; which is why it favored great Britain (coal) , Germany (Iron) and USA (everything).
If the limiting resource is Magic, and Magic can be gained through study and hard work, then the winners of the industrial Revolution are going to be China, India, or Russia: giant, entirely un-democratic countries with hundreds of millions of peons that can be put into simplified Magic Schools to brute force internal industrialization. If the scarce resource is people, people get treated like dirt, so whoever has the most people, and moral capacity to abuse them, wins.
So, your Industrial Revolution is MUCH darker, moves East, and leads to great inequality rather than a new shot at equality.

Yup if it happens, which it won't with what you've done so far, this is exactly what will happen with a magical industrial revolution where magic is expensive, and essential, to learn.

While a lot of this is valid, I question the last couple of paragraphs. Remember, India is under British control, and all the major European powers have large populations in their colonies Africa, Asia and the Americas. As for Russia and China, they're not short on natural resources as it is, and limiting factors such as corruption likely still apply. In other words, the form of exploitation of colonies changes, but there may not be a shift in the center of power.

@user111403 "Earth-like fantasy world" so the Earth specific geographic details aren't actually relevant, the sentiment, that large countries willing to exploit their populations mercilessly will win out, is relevant and astute.

Thanks for this answer! the deepening of divisions between social castes, and uncarring empires coming out on top could actually fit easily with the story I had in mind :)

@user111403, in a world where the greatest power is not a gun, or a cannon, or a fleet of galleons, bu personally wielded MAGIC gained through practice and meditation,  India would not be under British dominion, it would stomp Britain to the ground.  Not only India has much richer magical tradition, but has enough population to just crush the Brits under the magical boots of 30 million Sorcerer Kshatryas. If OPs world is like ours, then the level of Magic in each nation is opposite to their level of non-magical industrialism, so the nation with more magicians than Europe has people wins.

@BabiBaba, as I wrote in another comment, belief/skill in magic in a society tends to be inverse of their level of technological progress, so you might end up with a weird world in which powerful "sorcerer empires" colonize more industrialized nations, and rule over more technologically advanced (but less magically adept) people. Sort of an inverse of what Britain was doing IRL. I imagine Indian Brahmin-Sorcerers ruling over British "factory-witch" peons, as colonizers.

You're disregarding the OP's parameters. "This world’s technological evolution was roughly similar to ours until the 18th century". "[Magic] was never powerful nor common enough to affect agriculture, warfare, public health, industry, or commerce". Until the 18th century, the world's greatest power isn't magic, and by then Europe has already colonized a large part of the world. It's worth noting also that India was far from united before the British conquest, divide and conquer is still very much on the table.

@user111403 " A diligent worker can learn to operate them within a decade of performing menial jobs (pushing carts, feeding them powders and liquids, etc.) around them and meditating regularly. Children born of women working these machines can learn even faster." Lots of menial repetition AND meditation? This vastly benefits cultures with millennia of tradition of doing these exact things, mainly India and China.

Sure. India and China have strong magical potential. The point you're missing is, that potential is like oil reserves before the 19th century - there ready for future technology, but with no practical application and little value before that technology. By the time the technology appears to actually apply this magical potential, the colonial powers already dominate India. As for China, it's always had lots of potential even in the real world, but for whatever reason, it hasn't been able to fully apply that potential until the last half-century or so.

This is all kind of moot anyway since the OP's world is only earth-like, but the point stands: your answer is mostly excellent, but the dominant powers will be those with the largest exploitable population, which in an 18th-century setting are the largest colonial powers. That means, in addition to what you describe, you also have an even bigger division between the home countries and the colonies which will be exploited even more ruthlessly.

Frame Challenges
The three inventions mentioned don't get you an industrial revolution, they might get you a short burst of activity that depletes all the easily accessible deposits of key non-renewable raw materials and then stalls out. One of the greatest driver-enablers of the European industrial revolution was the steam powered beam engine used to pump out coal and other deep mines so that huge volumes of resources that were previously inaccessible were available for production. Without some equivalent increase in raw material supplies you can't have or sustain mass production. If your magical inventions rely on scarce magical materials or the input of a relatively rare spellcasting individuals the problem is even worse.
The industrial revolution also required that a large percentage of the rural population be freed from farm labour to work in cities. That requires that you remove human labour from the plowing, planting, and harvesting parts of the farming year. This labour was available during our industrial revolution because of the steam traction engine and the various tools that they could power, you don't have an equivalent device that creates an instant labour surplus. It will take several generations for the food surplus to translate into an expanded labour pool, and there will be issues around inheritance and poverty that will crush life expectancy and tank the population before that happens.

Thank you for your answer, I didn't think about all this... I'm going to try and find ways to add other inventions to the world to explain an increased productivity in mining and farming

@BabiBaba A lot of people don't realise how much historical technological progress required population densities to increase both to enable increases in production specialisation and to create a market for those specialised products. The way that steam engines outside of cities, factories, and transportation, changed European society isn't something that is immediately obvious but it was at least as vital to the increases in production as their direct role in the production itself.

I'll probably accept your frame challenge as an answer. But I'll ask just in case : do you have an idea on what would be the impact on urban développement of a slower migration of the workforce from farmlands to industrial cities ?

@BabiBaba That's what I meant about "inheritance and poverty", having more food but still needing the same amount of farm labour will lead to largely families, division of rural estates and rising poverty. The relatively sudden surge of available unskilled workers due to the mechanisation of farming created rural poverty at exactly the same time that urban centres needed an influx of that same labour to maintain the trajectory they had started on.

The Mana Revolution arose from investigations pursuant to the Act for the Settlement of Ireland 1652.  While pursuing stubborn adherents of Catholicism, Oliver Cromwell's men turned up evidence of ancient, peculiar rites and unnatural activities on the island.  Alchemists were unable to analyze the materials found, until Sir Isaac Newton, acting on a conversation overheard by chance, was able to make use of a precocious child to coax one of the captured artifacts to display its "animal magnetism".
For a brief time, several magnetic individuals made circuits of the courts of Europe as performers.  But at the same time, Removal Regiments began collecting tens of thousands of children and young women at a time from all over captive Ireland, confining them to tuberculosis-ridden workhouses until they succeeded in generating useful mana.  They were then coerced to sign indentures assigning them to owners throughout the British Empire, wherever major industrial activities of mining and farming could be assisted.  A particularly large number were exported to the colonies from Virginia to Georgia in North America.
Over time, as indentures seemed set to expire, the system was revised in many jurisdictions to become a more frank form of chattel slavery.  Slave raiders depopulated Ireland and the Basque country of Spain, based on speculative evidence that these peoples possessed greater mana capacity.  These rumors were replaced by science, when the young Jean-Baptiste Lamarck published detailed evidence showing that children of mana miners became better power sources than fresh-caught slaves.  As this directly impacted the profit margin, the early 1700s brought a worldwide shift from raiding to captive breeding of mana workers.  Profits were raised further when growth-accelerating technology was discovered: this was used both to provide the food for the slaves, and to accelerate the slaves' rate of physical development.  Slaves generated in this manner were intellectually deprived, visibly misshapen, and far more powerful than their human ancestors.
At the time of our snapshot, the industrial districts of the cities of Europe are linked by water roads - reflecting pools an inch or two deep, refilled by tankers that pass over the route, which can be used as trackways for a mana enchantment.  Mana slaves are confined almost entirely to iron containers designed for water-road travel, and used only on well-monitored routes accessible to the network, as a means of reducing the risk that disloyal elements will obtain the technology and use it for terrorism or export it to foreign potentates.  The slaves are taught a strictly limited set of concepts and actions that allow them to control their inner mana, and receive food or punishment based on their ability to carry them out.  Though paranoia among the owners has at times been intense enough to motivate them to mute their chattels, this is now only occasionally done as the rapid development, malformation  isolation, and frequent replacement of worn-out slaves has rendered them for the most part incapable of human communication.
Of course, scientists continue investigating the potential of this technology.  They frequently design new devices and instruct slaves in their operation.  The social situation being as it is, the researchers themselves would not dare contemplate being seen attempting to operate a device with their own animal magnetism; thus the ongoing research they do is, by necessity, in conformance with the standardized use of mana-slaves in industrial applications.

O_O                               .........what!?

There is a common misconception that groups are enslaved or oppressed due to some innate inferiority, when in reality it is the opposite.  The U.S. imported Black slaves at great expense because only they could survive "seasoning" (continual exposure to malaria under miserable conditions).  Women were subjugated because they could produce new warriors.  The young, not the old, are at risk of the draft.  I could give other more debatable examples.  So I think giving these people an intrinsic superiority likewise exposes them to an increased risk of cruel exploitation.
